# Is there a way to highlight the cell based on different values on another cells

Tags: excel, vba, formula, cell

I struggle to create a formula to highlight a cell.
I am working with two different sheets on workbook: 1.Production & 2.Stock missing
I am updating Production sheet with production order numbers (Column G). Production order is unique and can't repeat on this worksheet.

When someone have a problem with stock, they add this number to second sheet (Stock missing) in column B. They are also clarifying Location of order in column F. Location of order could be "CW" or "TP"(nothing more). When problem is sorted for the particular production order, employees are choosing "YES" from drop down list in column K (the same "Stock missing" sheet).

I want to highlight production order number in RED (in "Production" Worksheet) if the production order number equals the same production order in "Stock missing" sheet and has location of order "CW", but when they choosing "Yes" in column K, color should disappear.
If location of order is "TP" I want to do the same as above, just highlight the cell in YELLOW.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! We can not code for you. Post what to tried, and then we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited version:

Try creating these conditional formatting for entire column `G:G` in sheet `Production`

(Home->Conditional Formatting->New rule->Use formula to determine which cells to format):

Use this formula and set fill to "No fill":

`=IF(Production!G1="",TRUE,INDEX('Stock missing'!K:K,MATCH(Production!G1,'Stock missing'!B:B,0),1)="Yes")`

Use this formula and set fill to "Red":

`=INDEX('Stock missing'!F:F,MATCH(G1,'Stock missing'!B:B,0),1)="CW"`

Use this formula and set fill to "Yellow":

`=INDEX('Stock missing'!F:F,MATCH(G1,'Stock missing'!B:B,0),1)="TP"`

Now sort them as in picture and it should be working.
[Order of rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A692T.png)

Comment: Hi. I made a mistake in my post. They updating column B in Stock Missing sheet with Production order number, and location in column F.
I will try to work around these formulas you have advised. Many thanks

Comment: You are welcome. If you have any problem I can adjust them for you but feel free to do it yourself. Have fun :)

Comment: I feel really silly with this. I think I am asking too much for excel. I have tried the formulas you have advised (really appreciate this), I was trying to work around to make them work, but it's just not working :/ My head is on fire lol 
So just to clarify: I need cell in column G be highlighted (Production sheet) just in that case if it matches cell B (Stock Missing sheet) and Column F says "CW". I was trying to find even VBA code for it, but when the knowledge of excel is basic, not much you can win :)

Comment: Hi again :) I edited my answer, also i changed picture to show you all sheets to see, hope it will make it clearer :)

Comment: You are my hero! I even have jumped of my chair from happiness when formula have worked! :D The top one still don't work when I'm choosing "Yes" in Column "K", but it's not a massive issue, I can think of something else. Most important that I have cells highlighted in red and yellow. I have no words how to say thank you. You made my day.  :) Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have that formula at top of your list like in picture ?  Other than that I don't know, it worked on my file.  You are welcome :)

Comment: Yeah, I do have it on the very top.  I chose a different color for it just to see what is going on, ant it just highlights about 20 cells in a row. Maybe I did something wrong (I wouldn't be surprised lol). Anyway. Thank you once again. I will try to investigate why the first one is not working for me. Have a lovely day ;)